# How to Use Time Difference of Arrival (TDOA) for a Transmitter Localization

Tags: estimation, localization

Does anybody know a source that illustrates the algorithm to use TDOA method to locate a transmitter? Would the equations to solve (x, y, z) of the transmitter location linear or non-linear? How about the iterative algorithm to locate a transmitter based on TDOA measurements?

Comment: I believe it's called the "submarine problem" but I haven't got a reference to it.  I did the analysis for a surface a long time ago.  Basically you want a triangle of sensors with one in the middle.  If you need more I will dig up that solution.  I think the final thing I used to resolve the set of equations was a Groebner analysis; although I am sure Maxima will solve them, but use the "supplemental" solution!  It's thorough in my experience.  A square area has ambiguities.